# Custom "Not Found" option in bootstrap-select when live searching

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

Using Bootstrap 3, and [bootstrap-select v1.13.2](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

I have created a bootstrap-select with live-search turned on. Below is a simple example.

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="customer" name="customer" data-live-search="true">
    <option>Customer Inc</option>
    ...
    <option>Customer LLC</option>
    <option>New Customer</option>
</select>
```

I would like it to display the New Customer option, if no other customers are matched while using the live search.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52827818/10629916) to a similar question, but I can't figure out where to put that code, and I can't comment to ask for clarification (brand new account).

**EDIT:**
Apparently the above referenced answer is for a completely different (albeit similarly named) plugin. Does anyone know if what I want to do is possible with the plugin I'm already using? It would be a pain to switch it out over many pages.

Comment: They downloaded the bootstrap select js file and modified that code directly.

Comment: @Ashley I know that, but I can't tell where in that file to put their code. I've looked through it 3 times, but I'm not familiar with bootstrap plugins, and It's almost 3k lines of code.

Comment: Just ctrl+f and search for it?

Comment: Tried that. I'm not familiar enough with bootstrap plugins to figure out where the search event gets fired off.

Comment: Ah, so that is actually because you're not looking at the same JS plugin... they are sepereate/different bootstrap selects

Comment: ohhhhh. Well maybe I'll try that plugin instead of the one I'm using. Thanks for the help.